# AMP equivalent of ready event

Tags: amp-html

Is there a way to bind an action to some kind of `ready` event in google AMP? I mean an event which is fired automatically when page (or some element) is loaded.

Comment: Hi, the closest is amp-bind but it fires only after an user interaction. Most components have placeholders, so you may be able to achieve the same behaviour you are looking for. Could you provide a scenario?

Comment: I would like to remove some query parameters from URL right after user enters the page. I know altering URL is rather not possible with AMP but I was wondering if there is a way to do some action after page is loaded

Comment: you could do it server side by redirecting to a new URL where the parameters are removed.